# Use class defined in file in script tag Laravel view

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, socket.io

I try to develop a project in laravel, and, among other things, i have to use socket.io.
I implemented a class as a wrapper for socket.io-client in its own file.
I import that file in laravel view.

I want to instantiate a socket object in a script tag in laravel view to be able to pass a variable from that view, but I get this error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Socket is not defined**

The question is, can I use in a script tag, a class defined in an imported file ?

LE: code provided

**Laravel view**

```
@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/diagram.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/socket.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        let socket = new Socket("http://localhost:8080", {!! $id !!});
        socket.connect();
    </script>
@endsection
```

**Socket wrapper (just a part of it)**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class Socket 
{
    constructor(strURL, diagramId) 
    {
        this.strURL = strURL;
        this.diagramId = diagramId;
    }

    connect()
    {
        this.socket = io.connect(this.strURL);
        // Send the diagram id to include socket into a room
        this.socket.emit('diagram', this.diagramId)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: I added the code. I hope is ok now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that `socket.js` is not loaded yet when js tries to execute inline script

Comment: Socket class should be already loaded, didn't it ? Aren't scripts loaded in order ?

Comment: ye, but they are loading asynchronously. so you can wrapping your code with `document.addEventListener('onload', function (){})` or `$(function () {})` for jquery case

Comment: it worked. thank you